# Can't get boostrap 3 navbar to show active colour correctly

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have implemented a bootstrap3 navbar to a site I'm creating for an assessment task at uni. I used a website to generate a semi-fancy navbar that features colors on mouse-over etc.

I'm trying to set up a script to highlight the active page (on the navbar), but I've  had no luck.

I have tried multiple attempts to setup a script but even using other questions for reference I can't get any to work.

Here is my navbar code (template from the navbar generator):

```php
<header class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand">FACEBOOK LITE</a>
        </div>
        <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.php" name="loginnav"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Login</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="register.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Register</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="main.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Home</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;My Account<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Account Preferences</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Log Out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Here is my custom css for the navbar (created by the navbar generator)

```css
.navbar-default { background-color: #1658BA}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus { background-color: #3D7EFF}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a,.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus { background-color: #3D7EFF}
.dropdown-menu { background-color: #D1E0FF}
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus { background-color: #3D7EFF}
.navbar-default { background-image: none; }
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus { background-image: none; }
.navbar-default { border-color: #080808}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand { color: #FFFFFF}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover { color: #FFFFFF}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a { color: #FFFFFF}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus { color: #FFFFFF}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus { color: #FFFFFF}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus { color: #FFFFFF}
.dropdown-menu>li>a { color: #333333}
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus { color: #FFFFFF}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a .caret { border-top-color: #999999}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a:hover .caret { border-top-color: #FFFFFF}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a .caret { border-bottom-color: #999999}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a:hover .caret { border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF}
```

And finally this is my head (bootstrap and jquery files as well as script that looked like it should be working):

```php
<head>
        <!--// Bootstrap Defaults //-->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


        <!--// JQuery Files //-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


        <!--// Bootstrap Files //-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!--// Navbar Active Script //-->
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('li.active').removeClass('active');
                $('a[href="' + location.pathname + '"]').closest('li').addClass('active'); 
            });
        </script>

        <!--// Custom CSS Stylesheet //-->
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="default.css">
</head>
```

As mentioned before I have tried a few different scripts and none seem to work.

All I would like is for the navbar to highlight the current .li (set the class="active") according to the current page I am on.

You can view the website here: http://titan.csit.rmit.edu.au/~s3605062

So you can see how the blue highlight works on mouseover, but it doesnt stay highlighted for the active page which is what I would like.

Any  help is much appreciated,
Thank you!

Ricky

Comment: Every time i click on a menu item, you reload the complete page. So in register.php you must set the register tab to active and in main.php you set the main tab to active. The java script you implemented does nothing, because the page is reloaded.

Comment: @Grumpy I unfortunately was doing this before hand manually but I wanted to clean up my code and put the navbar in a "header.inc" file that contains code that will be on every page (e.g. the navbar) How would I go about doing this if I don't have the navbar code specifically in every document? Something like this:


`<?php
 include("inc/header.inc");
 include("inc/register_new.inc");
?>

<h1>Create an account</h1>`

(Provided my nav code is inside header.inc) Is there not a script I can setup that will do this for me?